# Retrieving a JSON body from DB gives extra special characters - Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, oracle, spring-boot, jackson

We are saving a JSON response body in our Oracle DB which is later retrieved for the viewing purpose.

**This is the JSON saved in DB**

```
{"parameters": [{"name": "SEATS", "value": "Q1"}, {"name": "SEATS", "value": "Q2"}, {"name": "MEMBERS", "value": "Alen"}, {"name": "MEMBERS", "value": "Sara"}], "messageTemplate": "You have booked tickets, seat numbers are Q1,Q2", "url": "", "remarks": "ticket booked"}
```

**Now the response of our view API is like this - (with an extra slash)**

```
{
    "responseBody": "{\"parameters\": [{\"name\": \"SEATS\", \"value\": \"Q1\"}, {\"name\": \"SEATS\", \"value\": \"Q2\"}, {\"name\": \"MEMBERS\", \"value\": \"Alen\"}, {\"name\": \"MEMBERS\", \"value\": \"Sara\"}], \"messageTemplate\": \"You have booked tickets, seat numbers are Q1,Q2\", \"url\": \"\", \"remarks\": \"ticket booked\"}"
}
```

**Inspected value of the variable while debugging**

```
{"parameters": [{"name": "SEATS", "value": "Q1"}, {"name": "SEATS", "value": "Q2"}, {"name": "MEMBERS", "value": "Alen"}, {"name": "MEMBERS", "value": "Sara"}], "messageTemplate": "You have booked tickets, seat numbers are Q1,Q2", "url": "", "remarks": "ticket booked"}
```

**DB side**

Columns description : `VARCHAR2(500)`

**Update regarding usage of JSONObject**

I tried printing it `System.out.println(new JSONObject(responseBody));` like this. The console is printing the proper JSON body, but even if I use the same above logic there are still special characters.

**Spring Boot part**
**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/booking")
public class BookingReportsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private BookingReportsService service;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/more-info/{tnxId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Booking moreInfo(@PathVariable(name = "tnxId") String tnxId) {
        
        return service.moreInfo(tnxId);
    }
}
```

We tried returning both `Booking` and `ResponseEntity<Booking>` but the results were the same.

This is our response bean

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Booking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7480161196626214557L;

    private String txnId;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern =Constants.SETTLEMENT_PDF_DATE_FORMAT)
    private Date txnDate;
    
    private String userId;
    
    private String appId;
    
    private String appName;

    private double amount;
    
    private int status;
    
    private String responseBody;
    
    private String url;

    // getters and setters
}
```

We are getting an extra \ as an escape character, now if we beautify the JSON and put it in multiple lines we'll get `\r` & `\n` in the response. So how can we remove that?

Comment: Did you try printing one of these strings?

Comment: Is the return value from the database the same as the output of your api endpoint ?

Comment: @ScottHunter, yes I tried debugging it, and the value while inspecting was fine. Same is updated in the question

Comment: Can you share the code that is used to define the API? Are you using ORDS?

Comment: HOW are you retrieving the json..in other words, HOW did you implement your REST API?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Just annotated `private String responseBody;` with `@JsonRawValue` as follows:

```java
@JsonRawValue
private String responseBody;
```

**Explanation**
Because the value of `responseBody` is a JSON string and `@RestController` is going to serialize the return object of `moreInfo` into *HttpResponse* automatically. That's why you got "extra special characters" in your response body!

Therefore, the simplest way (by using `Jackson`) is to annotate those fields which you don't want to be serialized again with `@JsonRawValue`.

For more information, please refer to  [@JsonRawValue](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```java
String final_json= json.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

json is the string that has your json
i did four \ because if i typed one it will expect something like `\n` and `\r`

Comment: Gives me `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` with message java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\

Comment: I just updated the answer

Comment: Still the result is same

Comment: weird! it's working for me i guess you need to check your code

Comment: I think this logic won't work. While inspecting that JSON it looks fine, only when it's returned it's coming with an extra slash.

Comment: use that with the returned json.